# Aligning HTML elements with CSS

Tags: html, css

I have to style a simple HTML document. The two labels have to be positioned on the left, the dropdown boxes have to be center and the image has to be positioned on the right. So far I tried it with  but it does not work properly. There is always an element that is not correctly aligned. Please help me? Thanks in advance.

```css
.fist_section label {
  position: left
    width: 30%;
}

.fist_section select {
  position: center;
  width: 40%;
}

.first_section img {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <div class="first_section">
    <img src="../img/img.jpg">
    <label>Automobile:</lable>
    <select class="fist_section_dropdown">
      <option value="bmw">BMW</option>
    </select>  
    <br> 
    <label>Automobile:</label>
    <select class="fist_section_dropdown">
      <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: `position` is not to position to the left, right or center. Is to define absolute, fixed, static or relative positioning. That's why position doesn't works as you like. See more :  https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/position

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are too many typos here such as `.fist_section` should be `.first_section`, `<\lable>` should be `</label>`, and so on.

`position` is not used for alignment but for defining `absolute` or `relative` positioning. What you really need to write here is `float: left;`.

```css
.first_section label {
    float: left;
    width: 30%;
}

.first_section select {
    width: 40%;
}

.first_section img {
    float: right;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <div class="first_section">
    <img src="../img/img.jpg">
    <label>Automobile:</label>
    <select class="first_section_dropdown">
      <option value="bmw">BMW</option>
    </select>  
    <br> 
    <label>Automobile:</label>
    <select class="first_section_dropdown">
      <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are using invalid properties. There is no `position:center;`, etc, only this:

```
position:relative;
position:absolute;
position:fixed;
```

You need to make each item's position `absolute`, and then add their `right` and `left` properties to position them.
Here is an example:

```
position:absolute;
left:0;

position:absolute;
right:0;

position:absolute;
left:50%;
margin-left:-(half the elements width)px
```

You can also try using `display:flex;` but this is not the best option for older browsers.

`display:inline-block;` will work if you don't want the item positioned `absolute`.